# How to pass connection string that has a backward slash to SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to call the stored procedure using  C#.

I am facing problem in the following line.

```
SqlConnection("Server=DB2\XPT;DataBase=SCFHP_EDI_P1;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

The part that I am not able to use is the server `DB2\XPT`.

What do I need to do to use server name as `DB2\XPT`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
("Server=DB2\\XPT;DataBase=SCFHP_EDI_P1;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

or

```
(@"Server=DB2\XPT;DataBase=SCFHP_EDI_P1;Integrated Security=SSPI")
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape the backward slash `\`  in your connection string or use the `@` symbol if you want to avoid escaping characters in your string.

[**Read more about it on MSDN.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

#### Corrected syntax 1 using @ symbol:

```
SqlConnection(@"Server=DB2\XPT;DataBase=SCFHP_EDI_P1;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

#### Corrected syntax 2 using escaping:

```
SqlConnection("Server=DB2\\XPT;DataBase=SCFHP_EDI_P1;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```