# Unable to restrict backslash to single slash in the username in connection string C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Below is the code that I am using for connection string. The user name is ZA\Ankur.Deshpande. But I am getting error if I am putting 1 backslash and if I use @ it still gives me 2 backslash and its failing during my connection open.

```
var s = @"ZA\Ankur.Deshpande";
string connectionString =
"Data Source=03RNBL-5CD717;" +
                      "database = ankur; uid = " + s + " password = uuwwss@1988; ";
con.Open();
```

Comment: Do you mean backslash `\ `? Note that the debugger displays the backslash as `\\ `.

Comment: I mean "\" this. My username is ZA\Ankur.Deshpande for Sql server

Comment: Why would you create a  SQL Authentication`LOGIN` with that name in the first place? You should endeavour to make object names not need to be delimit identified (obviously Windows Authentication logins need to be, due to the `\ ` but we're talking about a SQL Login here).

Comment: @Larnu : Its windows auth hence i have to use ZA\.

Comment: @user3004443 you are using SQL Authentication above, not Windows.

Comment: @Larnu : Awesome . Thanks.. Replace my connection string.

Comment: I can't, @user3004443 , you'll need to create an appropriate SQL authentication `LOGIN` and `USER`s on your instance, with the minimal needed permissions, and then change the connection string above for that new `LOGIN`. Or, if you do you want to use Windows Authentication, you'll need to run the app under the credentials of the Windows Account you want to connect as or implement impersonation.

Comment: For Windows authentication, omit the username and password and specify "Integrated Security=SSPI" instead. The current process windows credentials will then be used, which need to be `ZA\Ankur.Deshpande` in your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass connection string that has a backward slash to SqlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542565/how-to-pass-connection-string-that-has-a-backward-slash-to-sqlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

Add two back slashes instead of a single back slash, without using @.